# How to check S.M.A.R.T. HDD Status in CoreOS

Tags: docker, smart, coreos

How to check the status of the hard discs ([S.M.A.R.T.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/S.M.A.R.T.)) in the CoreOS?

**smartd** and **smartctl** are not part of the CoreOS.
So following CoreOS philosophy smartd would run inside of the container, as a [systemd unit](https://coreos.com/using-coreos/systemd/) and smartctl would be used from [toolbox](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/install-debugging-tools.html).

I was not able to access hard drives from the toolbox.

Comment: Isn't the point of _the cloud_ not to have to worry about things like hard disks and SMART status? :) ;)

Comment: If you host your own private cloud you would want to check the status of the machines that are part of your cluster. _Example: you would like to get notification that hard drive has failed or that it  is going to fail soon, so it can be replaced._

Comment: You pretty much need a privileged container, which is also granted access to the appropriate devices. I don't think the device specials are passed in to the toolbox container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer here
https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/484#issuecomment-165174597

**On CoreOS host**

```
~$ toolbox dnf install -y smartmontools
~$ toolbox --bind=/dev:/dev smartctl --all /dev/sda
```

You may get "Operation not permitted error", then use bind directly:

```
~$ toolbox --bind=/dev/sda:/dev/sda smartctl --all /dev/sda
```